# Laravel, правильно ли так выводить страницы?

Tags: php, laravel

роут:

```
Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@page')->where('url', '[a-z]+');
```

контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $category;
    protected $page;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }

    public function page($url) {
        $page_info = DB::select("select * from pages where url ='". $url ."'");
        $title = $page_info[0]->title;
        $description = $page_info[0]->description;
        $catalog = $this->category;
        $page = $this->page;

        return view('page', ['page' => $page, 'catalog' => $catalog, 'title' => $title, 'description' => $description]);
    }

}
```

вьюшка:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
  <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
  <p>{{$description}}</p>
@endsection
```

Подскажите плиз, такой способ рабочий, НО что-то подсказывает что так делать нельзя (не профессионально). Может подскажите как лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Используйте **Eloquent** или возможности **Сервис контейнера**, это куда проще и удобней.

   Если используете Laravel **7** можно сделать так.

   ```
   //Route.php
   Route::get('page/{page:slug}', 'PageController@show');

   |------------------------------------------------------------|

   //PageController.php
   public function show(Page $page)
   {
       return view('page', compact('page'));
   }

   |------------------------------------------------------------|

   //page.blade.php
   @section('content')
     <h1>{{$page->title}}</h1>
     <p>{{$page->description}}</p>
   @endsection
   ```
2. Давайте осмысленные и запоминающиеся имена переменным и методам, у вас свойство `$page` вместо **1** страницы содержит коллекцию.
3. Список всех страниц и категорий можно вынести [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) или попробовать использовать новые [компоненты](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components)

p.s. Посмотрите курсы от Laracast по Larvael.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за ответ и советы. Но такой способ у меня не работает, 404 ошибка...

Comment: @ilyaaa521, можете оставить свой роут, а в контроллер добавить `show($url) { $page=Page::where('url', $url)->get();}`.

Comment: Большое спасибо еще раз, работает! $page_info = Page::where('url', $url)->get(); смотрится лучше чем $page_info = DB::select("select * from pages where url ='". $url ."'"); Правда не понимаю, чем лучше такой подход кроме удобства и читабильности кода.

Comment: @ilyaaa521, Eloquent ORM предоставляет возможность работать с базами в ООП стиле. Это у вас сейчас простой **SELECT**, а дальше пойдут более сложные запросы с которыми Eloquent справляется лучше и быстрее, чем это будете делать вы. Вам нужно посмотреть реальные примеры работы с Eloquent и сразу поймете преимущества.

Comment: Принял! А есть прмиеры стоящие? )

Comment: @ilyaaa521, посмотрите курс от Laracast и читайте документацию. Как пример можете рассмотреть раздел **Relationships**. Насколько просто получать связанные данные через Eloquent, а не строить свои запросы с кучей `JOIN` и их пост обработкой.